# Uploading image can't saved at directory and having error "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given "

Tags: laravel

i have a view input like that :

```
 <form class="form-group" action="/user6" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody><tr>
      <th style="width: 10px">#</th>
      <th>Pertanyaan</th>
      <th style="width: 60px">Tidak Baik</th>
      <th style="width: 60px">Baik</th>
    </tr>

    <div class="form-group">
        <tr>
          <td>1.</td>
          <td><input class="form-control" style="border:none"   type="text" name="question1" value="Kondisi, kebersihan, pelumasan bearing" readonly></td>
          {{--  <td><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder=".input-lg"></td>  --}}

          <td>
              <label><input type="radio"  name="answer1" value="tidak baik" checked></label>
          </td>
          <td>
              <label><input type="radio"  name="answer1" value="baik"></label>
          </td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td> <input class="form-control" style="border:none"  type="file" name="image" value="" readonly> </td>

            </tr>

        </div>


        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td> <div class="form-group">
                <label>Catatan</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="catatan" rows="3" placeholder="Enter ..." required></textarea>
             </div>

        </tr>


    <input type="hidden" name="alat_id" value="7">
    <input type="hidden" name="status"  value="3 Bulanan">             
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

  </tbody>

</table>
      <div class="box-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="name" value="post">Submit</button>
       </div>
</form>
```

and to save this i have controller :

```
 public function store6(Request $request)
{

    if($request->hasfile('image'))
     {

        foreach($request->file('image') as $file)
        {
            $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);  
            $data[] = $name;  
        }
     }

    $user = new pemeliharaan;
    $id = Auth::user()->id;

    $user->user_id = $id;
    $user->alat_id = $request->alat_id;
    $user->pertanyaan =json_encode($request->except
    (['_token','name','alat_id','status','catatan']));
    $user->catatan = $request->catatan;
    $user->status = $request->status;


    $user->save();
   //dd($user);
    return redirect('user/show6')->with('success', 'Data Telah Terinput');

}
```

before i add "enctype="multipart/form-data" , my view dont have error BUT cant display and saved image at directory . i want saved image to directory but cant saved .
i create a folder named 'images' at public . after i add enctype="multipart/form-data" . this view having error "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given "

its my view after input :

```
 <table class="table table-condensed">
                    <tbody><tr>
                      <th style="width: 10px">#</th>
                      <th>Pertanyaan</th>
                      <th>Hasil</th>
                      {{--  <th style="width: 40px">Label</th>  --}}
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>1.</td>
                      <td>{{ $pemeliharaan->pertanyaan['question1'] }}</td>
                      <td>
                          {{ $pemeliharaan->pertanyaan['answer1'] }}
                      </td>               
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                      <td>2.</td>
                      <td>{{ $pemeliharaan->pertanyaan['image'] }}</td>
                      <td>
                          {{ $pemeliharaan->pertanyaan['image'] }}
                      </td>
                    </tr>


                      <td><img src="{{ url('images/'.$pemeliharaan->pertanyaan['image'])}}"></td>



                  </tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something in your table is array, it's not a string so when you put it inside `{{}}`, it will show error.

You should check

- `$pemeliharaan->pertanyaan['question1']`
- `$pemeliharaan->pertanyaan['answer1']`
- `$pemeliharaan->pertanyaan['image']`

by using `dd()` function.

Comment: i dont know what happen . my dd like that ."pertanyaan" => "{"question1":"Kondisi, kebersihan, pelumasan bearing","answer1":"baik","image":{}}

Comment: how this image just {}

Comment: if i add  enctype="multipart/form-data" , this data will image:{} , but if not using encytpe , its will show like this "image":"img.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

Deal with one problem at a time. At present you are storing the image but not saving the path to the file, which you saved in $data.  You are not using $data anywhere.

Then you have a problem rendering the new model in the view. This is a totally different issue and is caused by having non-string data passed to the htmlspecialchars function which is what {{ }} does.